# YUI3 Autocomplete: How to get value from after select event

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, yui3, yahoo-finance

I'm implementing application to obtain stock information from Yahoo Finance API using YUI3. I've done the autocomplete list but face a problem on how to get the value after user click mouse or press enter on the list.

Here is my code. The problem is that mynode.after(...) gives an error but I have no idea why and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
   YUI().use('autocomplete', function (Y){
    mynode = Y.one('#comsymbol');
    mynode.plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
        activateFirstItem: true,
        enableCache: false,
        source: function(query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: true,
                type: "GET",
                jsonp: "callback",
                jsonpCallback: "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback",
                data: {query:query},
                url: "http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc",
            });

            YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback = function(data) {
                var result = data.ResultSet.Result;
                var lists = new Array();
                for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ) {
                    var sb = result[i].symbol;
                    var nm = result[i].name;
                    var xch = result[i].exch;
                    var all = sb + ", " + nm + " (" + xch + ")";
                    lists[i] = all;
                }
                callback( lists );
            };
        },
        }

        mynode.after('select', function (e) {
            getStockInfo();
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must attach the event listener to the `AutoComplete` instance rather than the `Node`. The `AutoComplete` instance can be accessed via the `ac` member of the `Node`, and from there you can simply attach your event callback as you had before:

```
mynode.ac.after('select', function (e) {
    getStockInfo();
});
```

Take a look at the [YUI AutoComplete tutorial](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/) ([As a Plugin](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/#as-a-plugin) section specifically) for more details.